# Different font vertical align in line on OS X

Tags: css, windows, macos, fonts, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with fonts, because they don't render same on Windows and on OS X. On Windows, characters are vertically aligned in line, but on OS X, the characters are positioned much closer to top of the line.
I highlighted the text in screenshots so you can see the difference.

I am using font Gotham. Any ideas? Do I have to use browser-specific hacks or is it a font issue?

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wewo/myh4amud/

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Gotham', Arial, sans-serif;
 background-color: #282828;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

div {
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>3</div>
```

[image: PC screenshot]

---

[image: Mac screenshot]

Thank you!

Comment: used to line-height in your div and remove padding

Comment: Rohit Azad, that doesn't help. You can try in JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wewo/myh4amud/

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/myh4amud/1/

Comment: Google 'font renders differently' -- typefaces do display differently on different platforms, unfortunately. Here's an [interesting article on the topic](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/).

Comment: Rohit Azad, your example looks same on Mac. The text is not centered vertically in the middle, even if it has background color :)

Comment: i alarmed alien, so there is no way to solve this? I really need to center it for all browsers and OS :-/

Comment: The best you can do is set the vertical text alignment, font size and line height. Unless someone is browsing your website on two devices on different OSes at the same time, I very much doubt anyone will notice the difference.

Comment: They definitely will see the difference, as the text I am trying to align is big font (70px) in 120px sized circle and every difference  in center alignment is very visible.

Comment: @MatúšWewoBielik I have problem this align too, and now? You found way for solve this?

Comment: I found, answer posted =) I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in process converting or generating webfont font.

I use tool [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) for convert correct, with this option `EXPERT...` :

[image]

If don't work with Google Font, download him and send for convert.

Comment: no waaay, font squirred blacklisted font I'm using. I have exact same issue as topic starter. may be there are some css way of resolving this issue?

Comment: @Denis Try with software profissional and convert correct.

Answer (score 4):

Problem with `Win Ascent` and `HHead Ascent` fields in font. Windows use `Win`,
mac - `HHead`. Use `FontForge` for edit this.